ESP32-S3 Stuck at a Crash and Not Auto Resetting
Given below is a short version of the Arduino code I used to program ESP32-S3. On some occasions the program crashes and unlike normal crashes this one get stuck there without Auto-resetting
static void setup2()
{
    Serial.println("Setup (runnning on 2nd core)");
}


static void loop2()
{

    HandleConfigButton();
    HandleActivity();

    // To resolve core panic because of Watch Dog Timer not being reset
    delay(1);
}



// This is task running on the second core of ESP32
void TaskOnCore2( void * pvParameters ){
    Serial.print("Task running on core ");
    Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());

    // One time setup
    setup2();
    for (;;)
    {
        // Loop function
        loop2();
    }
}


TaskHandle_t HandleTaskOnCore2;
void LaunchLoopOnSecondCore()
{

    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                TaskOnCore2,         /* Task function. */
                "TaskOnCore_2",      /* name of task. */
                10000,               /* Stack size of task */
                NULL,                /* parameter of the task */
                1,                   /* priority of the task */
                &HandleTaskOnCore2,  /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
                ESP32_SECOND_CORE);  /* pin task to second core */

}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    LaunchLoopOnSecondCore();

}


void loop()
{
    HandleActivity();
}

The Crash Log:
Task running on core 0
Setup (runnning on 2nd core)Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception).
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (ipc1)
Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4037db37  PS      : 0x00060036  A0      : 0x8037c750  A1      : 0x3fcf1b10
A2      : 0x3fc94510  A3      : 0xb33fffff  A4      : 0x0000cdcd  A5      : 0x00060023
A6      : 0x00060023  A7      : 0x0000abab  A8      : 0xb33fffff  A9      : 0xffffffff
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x3fc94450  A12     : 0x7e140000  A13     : 0x08bb0000
A14     : 0x02c94510  A15     : 0x00ffffff  SAR     : 0x0000000e  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000
 
 
Backtrace: 0x4037db34:0x3fcf1b10 0x4037c74d:0x3fcf1b50 0x4037b02c:0x3fcf1b80 0x4037b022:0xa5a5a5a5 |<-CORRUPTED

 
 
 
ELF file SHA256: d451f74eeae971ec

I used ESP Exception Decoder and got this result
PC: 0x4037db37EXCVADDR: 
0x00000000

Decoding stack results

0x4037db34: xPortEnterCriticalTimeout at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/compare_set.h line 25
0x4037c74d: vTaskSwitchContext at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/port/xtensa/include/freertos/portmacro.h line 578

Can Someone explain what is wrong here ? I am clueless here.

HandleActivity() appears to be called from the normal loop() task and also indirectly from your task named TaskOnCore2 . Does it contain mutexs/semaphores and what size is it at runtime ? Whatever, this does appear to  indicate that the stack sizes defined are insufficient: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (ipc1)
